# Scripts with dialog from Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a docker container which intentionally should serve node.js environment. Something similar to configuration described in this [article](https://docs.docker.com/examples/nodefromjs_web_app/). But I want to create my own project. Is there are a way to run `npm init` and generate package.json with container? If I run this command it fails on first question. How can I answer on those questions?

*N.B.: Its not a problem to create this file manually(or use -y option) but I think this usercase illustrate more  general concept*

**Note:** actually it's a kind of problem to run this command with -y option. When you do that you have the same dialog with questions

Answer (score 1):

A couple options

1. You could script the answers to the questions using bash or expect.
2. You could generate the file by answering the questions manually first, and use a docker ADD command to 
   copy it into your container.

I'd probably choose 2.  So this is more of a question about handling bash input, rather than about docker per se.